# How to rotate image continuosly in CSS3? Not only when hover

Tags: css, hover

I can rotate the image while starting the page and hovering.. But i like to rotate the image continuously like .gif format.**Not only when hover**.In java we have return function, like that any keywords is available??
 *i cant found the solution!! Pls help..!*

Comment: I was answering it. It's not off-topic.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/mN5qc/1/) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using an `infinite` CSS3 keyframes based animation.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='rotate'>Test</div>
```

**CSS3:**

```
#rotate{
    background: blue;
    top: 20px;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    -webkit-animation: cont_rotate 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cont_rotate{
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu73L/)

Comment: Thanks Harry..!! we given it in infinite loop, then why we set it to 2s ??

Comment: @AjithMaverick: 2s is the time for one loop for the animation to complete mate. That is from 0 to 360 degrees once. By the way, if you add the original code that you tried to your question there is a possibility that your question could be reopened.